# Is there a way to restrict certain users in ubuntu 16.04 of MySQL?

Tags: 16.04, mysql

In the case that the administrator account(s) would be able to run the mysql command(s) in the terminal and the certain user account(s) wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Linux system of permissions, this is very well possible. Look at the current permissions of the `mysql` executable:

```
~$ ls -l /usr/bin/mysql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4243880 jan 19 13:45 /usr/bin/mysql
```

There are three groups of permissions:

1. rwx (owner `root` may read, write, and execute the file);
2. r-x (others in group `root` may read and execute the file);
3. r-x (all others may also read and execute the file).

We will take away the last permissions, and allow only a group of users to execute the command.

First, create a new group `mysqlusers`:

`sudo groupadd mysqlusers`

Then, move the `mysql` executable to that group:

`sudo chgrp mysqlusers /usr/bin/mysql`

Check to see that it has worked:

`~$ ls -l /usr/bin/mysql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root mysqlusers 4243880 jan 19 13:45 /usr/bin/mysql`

Now take away the execution permissions for all "other" (non-mysql) users:

`sudo chmod o-x /usr/bin/mysql`

You may issue the `ls -l` command once more to check that the final `x` has been changed to a `-`.

At this point, if you tried to enter the mysql command, it would give you: access denied. That is because you are not a member of group `mysqlusers`. Add yourself and other users to that group:

`sudo groupadd -a -G mysqlusers [username]`

You will need to log out and back in for this last change to work.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying out chown to nobody:nogroup and chmod 600 from the administrator account, so that the non-mysql user can't access it but this process required me to be on root under the administrator account for mysql access.